# Continuously Animation of UILabel

Tags: objective-c, ios

How would you animate a UILabel continuously to four fixed points on the screen?

Comment: [UIView +animateWithDuration:]

Comment: check this might useful...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8398890/how-to-slow-down-an-animation-with-repeat-and-autoreverse

Comment: Use if conditions to set the frames in blocks.